# Url error in django social auth

Tags: django, django-urls, django-facebook

I am using django social auth in my app and I found a **Page not** found error.
I have installed it in my app and also place it in my project parallel to my app.

And I have also add url to my url file

url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),

But when it shows me the error It shows the list of url in my url file and where i have the required url which i am looking for.

The error page is as :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://abc.com/login/
Using the URLconf defined in webdev.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='home']
^polls/
^admin/doc/
^admin/
^register1/
^edit/
^edit1/
^customerreg/
^checkout/
^checkout1/
^order/
^order1/
^upload/
^upload1/
^product/
^profile/
^logout/
^login/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='socialauth_begin']
^complete/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='socialauth_complete']
^associate/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='socialauth_associate_begin']
^associate/complete/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='socialauth_associate_complete']
^disconnect/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='socialauth_disconnect']
^disconnect/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/(?P<association_id>[^/]+)/$ [name='socialauth_disconnect_individual']
The current URL, login/, didn't match any of these.
```

In the above list you can see that url file have that url , but it doesn't access that ??

Answer (score 1):

```
^login/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='socialauth_begin']
```

This url do not match with `http://abc.com/login/` as the url pattern requires a backend parameter.

Something like this will match the url you are accessing, however there is no backend parameter there, so in view you may want to choose something default.

```
url(r'^login/$', 'your_view',),
```

Comment: But then you may want to change the url that you are accessing.